# How to run a Wordpress wp_query without filters?

Tags: wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

I have a custom Wordpress plugin which searches for all posts of custom type Downloads and I need to query to find them all:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'download',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'paged' => $request['id'],
    'suppress_filters' => true
  );

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Unfortunately when I run the query, a plugin Easy Digital Downloads is overriding my query to include post__not_in which excludes some of the results I actually need:

```
"post__not_in": [
  "1241",
  "1343",
  "1452",
  "1467",
  "1247"
  ]
```

And I can see that the SQL that's generated looks like this:

```
"sql_query": "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (1241,1343,1452,1467,1247) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'download' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100"
```

I have tried deactivating EDD which makes my query work as expected but I thought that adding `'suppress_filters' => true` was supposed to undo when a filter was applied but I must be doing something incorrectly. I also checked the `pre_get_posts` that EDD generates (only one) and switched them off but that didn't work either.

How can I get the actual full results without the exclusion?  I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying to bypass filters added by the [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) plugin (by itthinx), and the `'suppress_filters' => true` parameter with `$posts = new \WP_Query( $args );` did the job.

You might also try the [`get_posts()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/), which returns a simple array of posts using the same (or similar?) `$args` parameter as `WP_Query()`. By default, for the `get_posts()` function, `suppress_filters` is `true`. Although it uses `WP_Query()` internally, it is intended to be used in a way that does not conflict with the main WP query loop. For me, `get_posts()` worked without having to explicitly provide `'suppress_filters' => true`.